# Why is the rendering of HTML a cpu intensive process?

Tags: html, performance, rendering, cpu, html-rendering

It's been often stated that the gating factor in html rendering performance is cpu.  I've also seen this by individually increasing cpu speed, amount of memory and disk speed and the only change that impacts html rending is cpu,

Why is the rendering of HTML a cpu intensive process (or said a different way, why is cpu speed the gating factor in html rendering)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculation of dimentions, spaces between elements, drawing small images, all that occurs *while* the browser is still loading the HTML page and maybe other resources, which also means several repositioning of those loaded elements. In very few situations you may get high memory page faults if large elements are found such as large SWF files or giant uncompressed images. But overall it's a process of calculation and recalculation, which CPU is the unit for the task.

Comment: Interesting point - this is really just a more specific case of rending graphics which is cpu bound as the result of it being heavy in calculations.  Hence GPUs to offload from the cpu. In the spirit of devil's advocate, while the rendering of high frame rate high resolution graphics while calculating 3D vectors and so on is obviously cpu bound due to all the math, in the browser case where are the big calculations really happening?  Or at least happening significantly enough to be a bottleneck, let alone a noticeable one.

Comment: Google announced few months ago the it intends to rank pages based on their rendering time * (regardless of download time), which means slower pages to render are the least to get a competitive rank. Sure, that led everyone questioning what can slow down a page. Ideas was to not use table based layout and reduce HTTP requests because table based layout increases CPU usage while rendering the page.

Comment: @rahmanisback: that's pretty ironic, given that the thing that most slows down pages I load is ads.

Comment: @MusiGenesis - AWESOME insight.  In fact, I get more and more frustrated as web sites have calls to google analytics, n other analytics packages, ads, facebook, and so on.  Yeah, browsers open up 2 connections per domain name and these all get executed in parallel on separate threads, but this background activity tends to significantly impair interactive browser functions like scrolling.  Nothing more frustrating than to try scrolling while the page load is in process and having to wait till it finishes.

Comment: @Howiecamp: I'm currently on vacation where my connection speed is slow, and the problem is so much worse. I'm wearing out my ctrl-alt-delete keys.